# Can a SQL Server Trigger send me an email?

Tags: sql-server-2008, email, stored-procedures

I wish to send an email from a `Trigger`, on my SQL Server 2008 machine. The data of the email will be, basically, some of the Trigger information.

Can someone provide some simple/sample code on how to do this, please? E.g. what's the system stored procedure called? Etc.

I've not set up any SQL mail and stuff, so I'm guessing it's built in and I can leverage that. But just to be sure: do I need to install any extra software on the server?

Comment: Yep. [http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/)

Comment: Can you? Yes. Should you? Absolutely not, IMHO. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This example sends an e-mail message to a specified person (MaryM) when the titles table changes.

```
USE pubs
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects
      WHERE name = 'reminder' AND type = 'TR')
   DROP TRIGGER reminder
GO
CREATE TRIGGER reminder
ON titles
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 
AS
   EXEC master..xp_sendmail 'MaryM', 
      'Don''t forget to print a report for the distributors.'
GO
```

Source : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Triggers should be kept to a minimum time.  Atomic database updates / inserts / deletes should be allowed to be as fast as possible.  Consider adding a separate table which the trigger can insert data into which a separate process monitors and initiates an email based on the contents.

Of course, this doesn't address whether or not it's possible to use TransactSQL to create an email - I'm curious about that one myself!

Comment: Re: Triggers - yep. i know that, etc. etc. And this is only for deletes .. and only for some debugging purposes AND on some low activity tables AND sql email is async, i believe ..

Comment: Database mail is, but SQLMail and other variants (especially using CDO via sp_OA) are not.  In your original question you didn't say you were using database mail, you actually said SQL mail.  There is a big difference.  In any case, even if you are using database mail on your current system, what if you move your code to another system where you can't use database mail for some reason?